# AT&T syntax error: junk '(rbp)' after expression when assembling incq -8(rbp)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

i got these errors when i tried to compile my code and i dont know why. Could anyone help me. I am writing in the AT&T syntax
Errors: error junk '(rbp) after expression on the lines noted with *** in the inout subroutine

Code:

```
.text                   #section directive intended to hold all instructions

formatint:  .asciz  "%ld"

formatstr:  .asciz  "%s"        #format string for string printing, the s stands for string

DNNIDA:     .asciz          "names: x and y \nnetID's: xID and yID\nThis is assignment 1b inout\n"   
enter:      .asciz          "\n"



.global main                #this is the main label


main:

    movq    $0, %rax        #no vector registers in use for printf (labmanual)
    movq    $formatstr, %rdi   
    movq    $DNNIDA, %rdi       #load adress of string to rdi register
    call    printf          #printing the string that is displayed on top

    call    inout           #calling the inout subroutine

    movq    $0, %rax        #no vector registers in use for printf (labmanual)
    movq    $formatstr, %rdi
    movq    $enter, %rdi        #load the adress off the next string into rdi register
    call    printf          #printing the enter string (a return)
    call    end

end:

    mov     $0, %rdi        #load program exit code
    call        exit            #exiting the program

inout:

    pushq   %rbp            #Prologue: push the base pointer   
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      #copy stack pointer to RBP

    subq    $8, %rsp        #reserve stack space for variable
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rsi      #load adress of stack var in rsi
    movq    $formatint, %rdi    #load first argument of scanf
    movq    $0, %rax        #no vector registers in use for printf (labmanual)
    call    scanf           #call scanf

    movq    $formatint, %rdi
    movq    $0, %rax        #no vector registers in use for printf (labmanual)
    ***incq    -8(rbp)         #increments the number by one

    ***movq    -8(rbp), %rsi       #move a return value into RAX
    call    printf          #call printf
    movq    %rbp, %rsp      #Epilogue: clear local variables from stack
    popq    %rbp            #Restore caller's base pointer
    ret             #returns from subroutine
```

Comment: I think the `%` is missing.

Comment: where am i missing the %?

Comment: The lines where the error occurs are the only lines where you use `rbp` instead of `%rbp`

Comment: YEAAHH THANKS BOIII. I think there is an error in the manual i got. Anways thanks

Comment: No problem:) I'm not very well versed with AT&T syntax, but it seemed odd.